# Same array of objects behave different in similar for loops

Tags: javascript, ajax

I cannot figure it out why list of objects behave different in same for loops.In second console.log i got few undefined fields and have more objects in array than first one.Screenshots and code are shown below. Any help please?

```
          $.ajax({
          url: 'https://manage.tagman.com/tm-api-ajax/tag-instance?_fields=id,name,containers',
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data){
              var instances = data;
              var test=[];
              for(var k = 0; k<newEvents.length; k++){
                  for(var m =0; m<newEvents[k].tagInstances.length; m++){
                     for(var z=0; z< instances.length; z++){
                       if(newEvents[k].tagInstances[m].id === instances[z].id){
                           for(var w = 0; w < instances[z].containers.length; w++){
                             var getId = instances[z].containers[w].split('/');
                             var containerId = getId[getId.length - 1];
                             newEvents[k].tagInstances[m].containers = containerId;
                             test.push(newEvents[k].tagInstances[m].containers);
                           }
                       }
                     }
                  }
              }
             console.log(test);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://manage.tagman.com/tm-api-ajax/container',
                        type: 'GET',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data){

                          var container = data;
                          var test2 = [];

                          for(var p=0; p < newEvents.length; p++){
                            for(var q=0; q < newEvents[p].tagInstances.length; q++){

                              test2.push(newEvents[p].tagInstances[q].containers);

                            }
                          }
                          console.log(test2);
                        }
                    });
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the data from the 2 distinct urls are different?? Did you confirmed it ?

Comment: Try to add `console.log(data);` after `success: function(data){` , and confirm what you are getting.